# Restrict access to edit page for specific user

Tags: users

I have 2 accounts where I need to prohibit them from editing the profile. I managed to hide the edit button but when I type edit into the URL it still allows them to edit the user profile.

```
if ($user->uid == 267 OR $user->uid == 268){
} // demo profiles, prohibit editing profile
else{
print l(t('Edit My Profile'), "user/{$GLOBALS['user']->uid}/edit");
}
```

I can't do this based on their role. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just limit profile editing to some role, like *no demo* or whatever you want to call it?

Comment: because the role would change the type of the account. These demo accounts need to have the same roles as the rest.

Comment: Why? I still can't see how adding *demo* and *non-demo* roles would cripple the demo purpose of an account, if only differences it would introduce are the ones you will have in place anyway, one way or another.

Comment: ok, what permission to check, to prohibit the roles from editing their profile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [Edit own user account permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/edit_own_user_account_permission).

> This module add 'edit own user account' permission.
>
> The goal of this module to prevent changes in user account information in the demo sites.

Or to do it in code:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['user/%user/edit'])) {
    $items['user/%user/edit']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_user_edit_access';
  }
}

function mymodule_user_edit_access($user) {
  if ($user->uid == 267 || $user->uid == 268) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  else {
     return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand that. It's working now, thanks a lot. It was caching. See, why do I always have to clear the cache?

Comment: You can turn off caching (and I usually do on development sites).  However, without caching, Drupal runs much slower, so the default is to have caching enabled.  Than, when you add features that impacts on the UI, you need to clear the cache for the change to have an effect.